# Finding all functions f(y) such that a differential equation becomes exact

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody help me with this question?

Find all functions f(y) for which the differential equation becomes exact:

$$ x^2 + \frac {f(y)}{xy} + ln |xy| \frac {dy}{dx} = 0 $$

If I set $P(x,y)=x^2 + \frac{f(y)}{xy}$ and $Q(x,y)= ln |xy|$, I get $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{f'(y)}{xy}-\frac{f(y)}{xy^2}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac {1}{x}$.

The differential equation is exact when $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$.

How do I go about finding all equations f(y)?

Answer (score 1):

Both derivatives are slightly wrong. Use 
$$
\frac{∂}{∂y}\frac1{xy}=-\frac{x·1}{(xy)^2}
$$
or treat $x$ as a constant factor from the beginning, and use
$$
\ln|xy|=\ln|x|+\ln|y|, \qquad\frac{∂}{∂x}\ln|x|=\frac1x
$$
to correct the derivatives.

Comment: I did derive the way you stated, and i've recalculated a few times and I get the same results.

Comment: There is still an $x$ too much in the derivative of $P$. You should end up with $f'/y-f/y^2=1$.

Comment: I see where I went wrong now, thank you so much for making me more aware of my silly mistakes! How do I proceed to the next stage?

Comment: This now is a linear differential equation for $f$.